# unable to pass spring profile from gradle command line

Tags: spring, spring-boot, gradle

I have gone through multiple suggestions in stackoverflow but unable to do it.
I have spring boot gradle app and trying to execute and run the gradle build through command line. I want to pass teh spring profile also while executing so.

I tried adding

```
bootRun {
systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

in gradle.build

and also tried

```
gradle bootrun -Pdev
```

command but it is not pciking up profile. I am very very new to gradle and dont sure what to do .

Comment: why do you need profile but while building?

Comment: i dont want to load profile while building , i can build by
    build.gradle
however i want to do 
    gradle bootRun 
and that time i want to use spring profile.

Comment: if i'm right profiles will be loaded at runtime, which means at the time of jar execution, while building it will just clean the local repo and create jar file with latest modifications

Comment: suppose i have two application.properties.dev and application.properties.prod and i want to use dev profile at this particular time. how do i do that. I use to use Maven and do the same using mvn spring-boot:run -Drun.profiles=dev

Comment: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-running-your-application.html#using-boot-running-with-the-maven-plugin look at this, it will run application, build is different and execution is different

Answer (score 6, accepted):

so i added below part in build.gradle

```
bootRun {
systemProperties = System.properties
}
```

and i used below command line command to pass spring profile.

```
gradle bootRun -Dspring.profiles.active=dev
```

i am able to see the below spring profile loaded logs.

```
  The following profiles are active: dev
```